# MySQL display a record for On Call shift

Tags: mysql, date, time

I am trying to get a specific record to show that falls between a start date and end date at a specific time.

Here is what I have in MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM OnCallCalendar
WHERE 
    CallDay <= CURDATE()
    AND CallEnd >= CURDATE()
    AND callTime < CURTIME()
```

So a call shift would start on 9/27/2014 at 7:00am and run to 9/28/2014 at 7:00am. The entries in the database would be something like this:

doctor | CallDay | CallEnd | callTime

smith   9/27/2014  9/28/2014  07:00:00

jones   9/28/2014  9/29/2014  07:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM OnCallCalendar
WHERE 
    NOW() BETWEEN CONCAT(CallDay, ' ', CallTime) AND Concat(CallEnd, ' ', CallTime)
```